# Haskell - getLine called before putStr

Tags: haskell

When I want to put some text before reading an input in Haskell, I tried writing it like this:

```
putStr "enter value: "
var <- getLine
```

However the output requires the user input before it displays the text:

```
[input]
enter value:
```

When I use `putStrLn` instead of `putStr`, it displays as it should:

```
enter value: 
[input]
```

Why do these two statements function differently? Is it the addition of the newline?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`putStr "enter value: "` actually writes to an output buffer, which is flushed to the actual standard output only later on, when the buffer becomes full or when a newline is found.

This is roughly the same mechanism found in the C programming language.

So, even if `putStr "enter value: "` is run before `getLine`, we don't see the output message, yet, which feels wrong.

The solution is to flush the standard output handle explicitly.

```
import System.IO
-- ...
putStr "enter value: "
hFlush stdout
var <- getLine
```